# Best practice for resize window with animation using ToolBar on Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, resize, window, toolbar, animated

I'm wondering what's the best practice to resize a window when Toolbar changes.

I'm trying to get this effect (animated) when a Toolbar selected option changes.

[image: Window size responds to Toolbar action.]

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my commonly used method:

After clicking the new toolbar item, firstly get the frame size of the new subview to be added, then change window's frame with animation.

*Demo (just change height, but you can add support to change width):*

```
- (void)switchToTabView:(NSView *)settingView withAnimation:(BOOL)animation
{
    NSView *windowView = self.window.contentView;
    for (NSView *view in windowView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    CGFloat oldHeight = windowView.frame.size.height;

    [windowView addSubview:settingView];
    CGFloat newHeight = settingView.frame.size.height;

    CGFloat delta = newHeight - oldHeight;

    NSPoint origin = settingView.frame.origin;
    origin.y -= delta;
    [settingView setFrameOrigin:origin];

    NSRect frame = self.window.frame;
    frame.size.height += delta;
    frame.origin.y -= delta;
    [self.window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:animation];
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. It works perfectly when you're programming directly in AppDelegate. Turns out I'm using an NSObject as AppController and I'm not able to use self.window.

Comment: @GoKu Where did you call this method?

Answer (score 0):

@GoKu Your answer gave me a hint how to solve it. I just added a new property for my window called "win".

Here's my solution:

```
- (void)updateView:(int)tag{
    [[_ourViewController view] removeFromSuperview];
    if (tag==0) {
        self.ourViewController = [[UserView alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserView" bundle:nil];
    } else if (tag==1){
        self.ourViewController = [[ComputerView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ComputerView" bundle:nil];
    }

    NSView *newView = _ourViewController.view;

    NSRect windowRect = _win.frame;
    NSRect currentViewRect = newView.frame;

    windowRect.origin.y = windowRect.origin.y + (windowRect.size.height - currentViewRect.size.height);
    windowRect.size.height = currentViewRect.size.height;
    windowRect.size.width = currentViewRect.size.width;

    [self.win setContentView:newView];
    [self.win setFrame:windowRect display:YES animate:YES];
}
```

Thanx!